# How to take off the "-" of the justified texts in Beamer

Tags: beamer, hyphenation, ragged2e

In the end of the line the justified text has "-" I would like to take off. Is there anyway to do that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or: 'brazilian' ?!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\justifying' macro
\begin{document}

\section{MERCADO DE CAPITAIS, CONSUMO E INVESTIMENTO}
    \begin{frame} 
    \frametitle{Consumo e Investimento sem Mercado de Capitais}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \justifying
    \setlength\itemsep{0.5cm}
    \item Quantidades de recursos que o indivíduo está disposto abdicar para consumo presente ou futuro é representada pela Taxa Marginal de Substituição (TMS).\vspace{0.5cm}
    \item A Taxa Marginal de Transformação (TMT) é a unidade monetária transformada em oportunidade produtiva para o consumo futuro.\vspace{0.5cm}

    \item Cada indivíduo obterá um equilíbrio, conforme a sua curva de indiferença, quando a TMS igualar a TMT. 


    \end{enumerate} 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `-`. Are you talking about the hyphens that mark line-broken word ("Marginal" and "monetária, I assume)? Aside: I'm assuming your code also loads the `ragged2e` package (for the `\justifying` directive) and loads the `babel` package with the option `portuguese` (or, maybe, `brazilian`).

Comment: Hey, Mico! Yes. I'm using ragged2e. When the text is ploted in the screen, the last word of the line is splited and comes this "-". I would like to maintain whole word in the line as is possible to do in Word of Microsoft.

Comment: @Arduin Just a small note, I introduces `\setlength\itemsep{0.5cm}` so that the items are automatically spread further apart and you don't need to do it manually using `\vspace{0.5cm}`. Combining both will further increase the spacing.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your code (and adding a couple of search tags) to make it compilable. Feel free to make further edits or to revert the changes.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to want to achieve two largely mutually-exclusive objectives:

- If you want the text fully justified, and if some of the words in the text are both quite long and amenable to hyphenation, TeX will hyphenate some words in order to generate a good-looking paragraph. One aspect of (typographical) "good looks" is that there should be no overfull lines and no unsightly large inter-word gaps.
- If you wish to suppress hyphenation entirely, and if some of the words in the text are quite long, some of the lines will be either seriously under-full (and feature large inter-word gaps) or massively over-full.

If your main priority is to suppress all hyphenation, don't load the `ragged2e` package -- after all, it is is *designed to permit hyphenation* -- and don't use the `\justifying` instruction.

Naturally, you are free to rewrite the text to (a) use fewer long words and (b) arrange portions of the text so that any long words don't occur near the ends of lines.

Finally, note that these points apply whether or not you use the `beamer` document class.

---

*Addendum*: If, for some reason, you truly must have both fully justified paragraphs in an `enumerate` environment *and* suppress all hyphenation, I suggest you (a) load the `hyphenat` package with the option `none` and (b) issue the directive `\sloppy` after `\justifying`, as is done in the following example. Speaking for myself, I'd say the results, especially the big differences in inter-word spacing from line to line, look *just awful*! You (and the people in the audience of your `beamer` presentation) would be much better off either allowing hyphenation after all or not imposing full justification.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel} % or 'brazilian' ?!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\justifying' macro

\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % <--- new
\begin{document}
\section{MERCADO DE CAPITAIS, CONSUMO E INVESTIMENTO}

    \begin{frame} 
    \frametitle{Consumo e Investimento sem Mercado de Capitais}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength\itemsep{0.5cm}
    \justifying
    \sloppy % <--- new
    \item Quantidades de recursos que o indivíduo está disposto abdicar para consumo presente ou futuro é representada pela Taxa Marginal de Substituição (TMS).
    \item A Taxa Marginal de Transformação (TMT) é a unidade monetária transformada em oportunidade produtiva para o consumo futuro.
    \item Cada indivíduo obterá um equilíbrio, conforme a sua curva de indiferença, quando a TMS igualar a TMT. 
    \end{enumerate} 

    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 The output looks really terrible - as bad as normally only word does :)

Comment: @samcarter - :-) I sure hope the OP gets the intended message.